# How to find UUID from AirTag Beacons

Tags: swift, uuid, ibeacon, beacon

I'm trying to make an AirTag Detector to my Final's Papers in SwiftUI, but I can't find them because they don't have any ID, just his Serial Number and I can't use that. Somehow I can create an app to simulate "Find app" from Apple or find UUID from IT?

If UUID doesn't work, have another way to do that?

I saw in this URL maybe we can't get AirTag's ID.
Is that true?
https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/airtags-bluetooth-id-tracking-explained.2294592/

```
import Combine
import CoreLocation
import SwiftUI

class BeaconDetector: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    var locationManager : CLLocationManager?
    var lastDistance = CLProximity.unknown
    
    override init(){
        super.init()
        
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        
    }
    
    
    func locationManager( _ manager:CLLocationManager,
                          didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus){
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self){
                if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {
                    startScanning()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func startScanning() {
        let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "d31bb872-27f2-11ed-a261-0242ac120002")! //Doesn't exist this UUID
        let constraint = CLBeaconIdentityConstraint(uuid: uuid, major: 69, minor: 690)
        let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(beaconIdentityConstraint: constraint, identifier: "Home")
        
        locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
        locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(satisfying: constraint)
    }
    
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRange beacons:
                         [CLBeacon], satisfying beaconConstraint:
                         CLBeaconIdentityConstraint) {
        if let beacon = beacons.first {
            update(distance: beacon.proximity)
        } else {
            update(distance: .unknown)
        }
    }
    
    func update(distance: CLProximity) {
        lastDistance = distance
        didChange.send(())
    }
}

struct BigText: ViewModifier {
    func body (content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(Font.system(size: 72, design: .rounded))
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var detector = BeaconDetector()

    var body: some View {
        if detector.lastDistance == .immediate {
            return Text("RIGHT HERE")
                .modifier(BigText())
                .background(Color.red)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        } else if detector.lastDistance == .near {
            return Text("NEAR")
                .modifier(BigText())
                .background(Color.orange)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        } else if detector.lastDistance == .far {
            return Text("FAR")
                .modifier(BigText())
                .background(Color.blue)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        } else {
            return Text("UNKNOWN")
                .modifier(BigText())
                .background(Color.gray)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SwiftUI isn't a language -- Swift is the language and SwiftUI is just a UI framework on top of it.

Comment: `switch detector.lastDistance { // switch cases }` would be a lot cleaner.